# Stored Procedure return null for OUTPUT parameter in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could you guys please help me to find the error in the below code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectCustomer2
    (@customerId INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @customerId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT * 
    FROM Sales.Customer
    WHERE CustomerID = @customerId;
END

--Executing SelectCustomer
DECLARE @lastRowId int

EXEC dbo.SelectCustomer2 @customerId = @lastRowId OUTPUT;

SELECT @lastRowId AS RowId
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`scope_identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) returns `null` because there's no `insert` in scope.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should probably read my blog post [Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SCOPE_IDENTITY**

Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

if in your scope dont have any insert the SCOPE_IDENTITY(); is null

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, Scope_Identity() returns last inserted value from column. I just insert data from Sales.Customer table to #temp table. And I want to get lastRowId using Output parameter and it returns NULL

Comment: @RamandeepSingh Mahdi just explained to you clearly what you are seeing. You have not inserted anything in the scope where you selected scope_identity. Perhaps you should read up on what a scope is.

Comment: Thanks guys It clears now. I was getting it wrong. I thought we can use it out of scope also. Thanks for clarify it